# devenv and dtsDebugHost in BIDS to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

My SSIS package is connecting to Oracle and getting data (tns entry is there in tnsnames.ORA to connect to the Oracle schema.).

When I run my SSIS package in my SQL Server through BIDS (SQL Server 2008R2) its hitting the Oracle with devenv.exe and dtsDebugHost.exe.

How it will hit to Oracle if I run through SQL Server Agent Job. Will it be through dtexec.exe? I am not permitted to test it in my Production SQL Agent, So, please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dtexec.exe will be the executable's name when you run this via SQL Agent (unless you do something special like run DTLoggedExec or write your own caller application)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will see dtexec.exe.

You need to make sure the Oracle Client is installed on the SQL Server - make sure choose the correct version 32 or 64 bit!

If the TNSNames are already installed on your production server then fine, otherwise I would recommend ditching TNSNames and maintaining within your package - makes things easier when you need to go live as it is one less thing to think about. You just need to copy the appropriate entry from TNSNames into the Server Name field:
[image]